# How to specify return type for a function returning a pydantic type according to an arguement value?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

I have two pydantic models, the second inheriting from the first:

```py
class RandomBaseModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    foo: typing.Any


class RandomSpecializedModel(RandomBaseModel):
    foo: str
```

Then I have a function that accepts some data and a model to use for instanciating a response:

```py
def do_something(
    data: typing.Any,
    response_model: typing.Type[RandomBaseModel] = RandomBaseModel
) -> RandomBaseModel:
    response = response_model(foo=data)
    print(f"---{type(response)}---")
    return response
```

Finally the result of this function is stored into typed variable:

```py
value_1: RandomBaseModel = do_something(42)
value_2: RandomSpecializedModel = do_something("42", response_model=RandomSpecializedModel)
```

This executes without any problem and works as expected, the `do_something` function instanciates a `RandomBaseModel` when `response_model` is omitted and instanciates a `RandomSpecializedModel` when it is instructed to use it. here is the output:

```
---<class '__main__.RandomBaseModel'>---
---<class '__main__.RandomSpecializedModel'>---
```

BUT this does not please mypy which complains with this message on line `value_2: RandomSpecializedModel = do_something("42", response_model=RandomSpecializedModel)`:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "RandomBaseModel", variable has type "RandomSpecializedModel")  [assignment]
```

**How could I inform mypy that this function returns an instance of the pydantic model passed as the `response_model` argument?**

---

To be clear: I am looking for a way to instruct mypy that this function could return a `RandomBaseModel` instance, a `RandomSpecializedModel` or an instance of any `RandomBaseModel`'s subclass.

---

I found some similar question whose answers suggested to use a TypeVar, so I tried to change the `do_something` function for this:

```py
AnyRandomBaseModel = typing.TypeVar("AnyRandomBaseModel", bound=RandomBaseModel)


def do_something(
    data: typing.Any,
    response_model: typing.Type[AnyRandomBaseModel] = RandomBaseModel
) -> AnyRandomBaseModel:
    response = response_model(foo=data)
    print(f"---{type(response)}---")
    return response
```

Although it still executes as expected, mypy now complains with:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "response_model" (default has type "Type[RandomBaseModel]", argument has type "Type[AnyRandomBaseModel]")
```

Comment: This is a known `mypy` limitation. See [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737) with solution examples.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably make the base model generic instead.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


class RandomBaseModel(pydantic.BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    foo: T


class RandomSpecializedModel(RandomBaseModel[str]):
    foo: str  # you might not need this line

def do_something(
    data: T,
    response_model: typing.Type[RandomBaseModel[T]] = RandomBaseModel
) -> RandomBaseModel[T]:
    response = response_model(foo=data)
    print(f"---{type(response)}---")
    return response
```

Comment: I probably have been unclear but my problem is about the return type of `do_something`, not the type of `RandomBaseModel.foo`. The specialized class inheriting from base model already exist and I cannot trash it.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed; `mypy` does static type analysis. There are always going to be valid Python programs whose behavior cannot be described by static types, and will require rewriting your code in a way that *is* capable of being described by static types. What you want to do--have the return type depend on the argument types in some way--is precisely what the idea of a generic class (aka parametric polymorphism) is designed to model. Unless there is something specific in Pydantic that I'm not aware of (I don't use it myself), you'll either need to rewrite your code or write adaptors.

Comment: yup, this suggestion looks right.  @Tryph it might be worth reading about covariance & contravariance of types, your code is trying to mix them up in a very unusual way that any type system would struggle to capture

Comment: I would be interested by your opinion about the solution I adopted described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72867926/2696355

Answer (score 0):

Try with an Union of types:

```
def do_something(
    data: typing.Any,
    response_model: typing.Type[RandomBaseModel] = RandomBaseModel
) -> Union[RandomBaseModel,RandomSpecializedModel]
```

I know it's weird as one of your class inherits from the other but I think that you do not have the choice

Comment: that is exactly what I tried to avoid. I only have one subclass for the moment but the number of `RandomBaseModel` submodels is intented to grow quite consequently :/

Comment: This only says that `do_something` can return a value of either type; it doesn't constrain the return value depending on the either argument type.

Comment: I would be interested by your opinion about the solution I adopted described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72867926/2696355

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, since I am not very happy with it, I solved my problem with `typing.cast`:

```py
value_2: RandomSpecializedModel = typing.cast(
    RandomSpecializedModel,
    do_something("42", response_model=RandomSpecializedModel)
)
```

This is not very satisfying to me to make it so verbose in order to just please Mypy, but at least it works without muting Mypy with a `# type: ignore[]`.
So this is good enough... :/